# Add a new object of a Model without going to /model/new in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have my Home page and a `Post` model.
If I want to add a new `Post`, I go to /posts/new and create a new object of a `Post` class. That is a standard way.

Can I include, for example, in my Home Page, a + button that will open a small window asking me to type title and content and have the same effect as the standard way ?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is yes.

You would have to follow next steps:

- your form for adding Post should be in partial
- Display this partial when + button is clicked
- Because you used the partial, action will be sent to Post#create
- Now you only have to consider redirect. If you have redirect on Post#create
- You can inside request send redirect page to homepage, if this is not done by ajax for some reason

This way you do not need to create anything new, just use the existing structure, that is what Rails is about. Place everything in small peaces and reuse them as often as you can.

Comment: I was thinking to do something similar. How can I get something like this to show? http://prntscr.com/bkg01e

Answer (score 1):

It is not very clear what you are asking but if I got it right you want to add Post from anywhere in your app. That is very easy you should either create an instance of model and create a partial _form.html.erb and render in your app

so inside controller

```
def index
  @new_post = Post.new
end
```

inside view:

```
<%= render partial: "form", locals: {page: @new_post} %>
```

inside _form partial

```
<%= form_for(page, remote: true) %>
...etc
<% end %>
```

If you generate scaffold Page you will get this partial by generator. There you can check how the partial is created.

Inside your view you can use what ever you want model...etc to display from for adding new. You can also check UJS to load the page with ajax so it does not refresh (remote: true) whole page

EDIT

here is the example if you want to use modal. I am using a bootstrap here but you can apply this anywhere. So inside your view (index for example) wrap the partial form inside markup of bootstrap) like this

app/views/pages/index.html.erb

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#new-page-modal"> Add Page</button>

<div class="modal fade" id='new-page-modal'>
  <div class="modal-content">
   <%= render partial: "form", locals: {page: @new_post} %>
</div>
```

You can include other part and have the button inside footer what will just trigger submit on form like $('#new-page').submit(); You would place this inside application.js

So inside view there is button that will trigger modal (data-target="#new-page-model"). I named the modal with this id so it opens if you have included bootstrap.js files inside asset pipeline. After that you can trigger form submit once the modal is visible.

EDIT 2

Here is how you can inside footer of bootstrap form have OK button trigger submit event

```
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn ban-primary" onclick="javascript:$('#new_form').submit();$('#new-page-modal').modal('hide');return false;">Save changes</button>
</div>
```

So here submit button since it is outside of the form I am triggering submit and closing the modal. You way want to one tune this if for example you want to handle errors, like Page Title is required...etc...for that it is best to use JS response with remote form.

Let me know if it is not clear.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I want small thing to pop up, like this: http://prntscr.com/bkg01e, in LinkedIn when you're editing your info, for example.

Comment: I updated my answer. I have not fully wrote markup of bootstrap but that is easy. There is a button that trigger modal and inside this there is a form ready to be submitted that creates new page (goes to pages controller create by default)

Comment: Thanks, it seems that it will work. I'll contact you and accept the answer if I get it to work

Answer (score 0):

For the small window you can use Bootstrap Modal. There's sample code [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

You can write the form [in a way](http://www.korenlc.com/remote-true-in-rails-forms/) that [automatically sends the query](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) via AJAX. You can write callbacks using the [listeners](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax) in order to display success or act otherwise.